# Reducing Polynomial Functions over a Finite Field

Tags: functions, polynomials, algebra, finite-fields

Over $\mathbb{F}_{4}$, for example, I am looking for a function that will, for example, reduce the polynomial ***function*** (not an element of the finite field itself) $$x^5 + 6x^4 +x^3 + 1 \rightarrow x^2 + x^3 + 1$$

using the identity $x^q = x$ over a finite field of order $q$, and the fact that $p=0$ for the characteristic of the field $p$ (2 in the case above). Again, I am not looking for a way to reduce something modulo some irreducible polynomial. I am just looking for something that will reduce the powers (e.g., $x^5$ to $x^2$ in the example above) and convert any zero coefficients to zero (e.g., $6x^4$ in the example above)

I would also be interested in any potential ways to write such a function. I would need it to work over multiple variables (e.g., $x,y,z,...$) also. Maybe I could use an if statement to check if the power was greater than $q-1$, although with multiple summed terms and variables I wouldn't be completely sure how to do that.

Any advice would be appreciated... Thanks

EDIT: This function seems to work (modified from cvgmt's reply) as well as the one from Carl Woll's reply:

```
GFReduce[f_, p_, q_, var_] := PolynomialMod[PolynomialMod[f, p] //. var^k_ :> var^Mod[k, q - 1, 1], p];
```

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`PolynomialReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolynomialReduce) for this:

```
PolynomialReduce[
    x^5 + 6 x^4 + x^3 + 1,
    x^4 - x,
    x,
    Modulus->2
] //Last
```

> 1 + x^2 + x^3

Comment: I think this is correct, and it seems to work. Would you mind explaining the reasoning behind $x^4 -x$ as the modulus? It makes some intuitive sense to me e.g. $x^5/(x^4-x) = x^2$ but I can't quite seem to pin down the reasoning

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```
p=2;
q=4;
PolynomialMod[x^5 + 6 x^4 + x^3 + 1, p] //. x^k_ :> x^Mod[k, q, 1]
```

> `1 + x^2 + x^3`.

Comment: Thank you! 

I modified it slightly to reduce via the characteristic again after the reduced powers are combined with any other like terms. I also changed the input to the Mod[] function from q to q-1.
For multiple variables you can just add another argument specifying the variable to reduce and apply it a second time for that variable:
GFReduce[f_, p_, q_, var_] := 
  PolynomialMod[
   PolynomialMod[f, p] //. var^k_ :> var^Mod[k, q - 1, 1], p];

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in function for this `PolynomialRemainder`.

Examples with constructed remainder:

```
Block[{f, d, rem, p = 7, q = 4},
 d = x^q - x;
 rem = x^(q - 1) + 1;
 f = (x^2 + 2 x + 5) d + p (x^4 + 5 x + 2) + rem;
 {PolynomialRemainder[f, d, x, Modulus -> p],
  GFReduce[f, p, q, x],
  rem}
 ]
(*  {1 + x^3, 1 + x^3, 1 + x^3}  *)

Block[{f, d, rem, p = 7, q = 4},
 d = x^q - x;
 rem = PolynomialMod[(x + p - 1)^(q - 2) // Expand, p];
 f = (x^2 + 2 x + 5) d + p (x^4 + 5 x + 2) + rem;
 {PolynomialRemainder[f, d, x, Modulus -> p],
  GFReduce[f, p, q, x],
  rem}
 ]
(*  {1 + 5 x + x^2, 1 + 5 x + x^2, 1 + 5 x + x^2}  *)
```

Comment: I think the point of the offset (third input into the Mod[]) function is so that x^3 does not reduce to x^0 = 1. That way, $x^{k(q-1)} \rightarrow x^{q-1}$. I think what the offset does is if x%3 = (0,1,2) it shifts it to (3, 1, 2).

Comment: @Kevin Yes, that's the effect. Somehow I didn't think you wanted that. But it seems you do, right?

Comment: Yeah basically I'm just trying to invoke the identity $x^q = x$. $x^{q-1} = x^0$ only if $x \neq 0$, which we don't know for sure, thus $x^{q-1}$ is left alone or $x^{k(q-1)} \rightarrow x^{q-1}$

Comment: @Kevin Sorry for not taking $x^q=x$ at face value. I adjusted `d` to reflect this.